# "any of my X" vs "any X of mine"?

Tags: differences, determiners, quantifiers

What's the difference between "any of my X" and "any X of mine"? My impression, as a non-native speaker of English, is that the latter sounds more formal.

I searched COCA Corpus, and I found:

- any of my X: total 808 hits
- any X of mine: total 67 hits (X is a single word, but multiple word cases are not so many.)

Note: You (usually) don't say "my any X" (but you say "my every"; see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/103884/9614).

Comment: They're both fine, I don't see a significant difference in meaning, and which one sounds more natural to me depends on what X is.

Comment: Without X and without context it's impossible to say. For example, if X is 'daughter' the meanings are utterly different.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: I wonder if you could explain how these two differ. It would help English learners, at least me, i.e. I don't know the difference. :P (Or if you think it's too obvious, I'll delete this question, and re-post it to ell.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Please tell me the *context* in which you want to use the expressions. Is X always an abstract noun? Is it always plural?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: I was simply curious, and since I'm clueless - my grammar books don't say any - it's completely up to you. But now I suspect this question is better asked at ell.SE, and not so appropriate for ESE. To make an answer valuable at this site, maybe it should discuss the origin of the difference of two, which look syntactically interchangeable. (None is responsible for such a burden. ;-)

Comment: @teika kazura "Curious and clueless" describes me pretty well! I certainly can't tell you the origins of these two formulae. I had never even considered the tiny differences in their usage. We take our own language so much for granted. I hope my answer is of some use to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the difference is not to do with formal/informal.

In **"any of my X"** I HAVE X.

In **"any X of mine"** I may or may not have X.

**"any of my X"** is common in everyday speech:
- If you need help please ask any of my staff.
- Were any of my ideas useful?

**"any X of mine"** is less common (as you discovered) and it gives greater emphasis to the word 'mine'. In fact when "any X of mine" is spoken the word "mine" is often stressed.

If **any of my students** would like to go to the concert would they please let me know.
If **any students of mine** would like to go to the concert would they please let me know.
- There is no difference in meaning at all between these two.

I wouldn't let **any of my children** go to that park.
- The meaning is clear. [If there were only two children then of course it would be "*either* of my children."]

I wouldn't let **any child of mine** go to that park.
- If I had any children (and I MAY have) I wouldn't let them go to that park.
Here there's an implied criticism of parents who DO let their children go to that park.

1) No-one has ever called **any of my soldiers** slovenly.
- The officer is not necessarily being proud here. He might even be amused.
2) No-one has ever called **any soldier of mine** slovenly.
- The officer is proudly taking the credit for having a smart platoon: smarter than yours perhaps.

NOTE! In sentence 1 it would be *possible* to stress the **my** and become as boastful as the officer in 2, though not as **pompous**. Perhaps it's this pomposity that you identified as formality. In certain situations "any X of mine" can sound rather superior.

Comment: There can be quite a difference between cases of 'any X of mine' etc where X is a non-count usage. 'I can't afford to spend any of my time on it'  and 'I'm not giving him any of my money' seem firm favourites (though 'I can't afford to spend any time of my own ...' is idiomatic).

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: Very lucid explanation! Let me attempt to clarify from where the differences come from. (1-a) In "any of my children", "my children" already implies they exist, I think , but (1-b) "any child" can be fictitious, and if they exist, they necessarily belong to me. If parentheses indicate precedence (like math), it's "any of (my children)" vs "(any child) of mine" that matters here.

Comment: (2-a) "Any of my soldiers" is similar to the above. It simply means "none of my soldiers". Ok, but I'm not sure of the other: (2-b) "Any soldiers of mine" sounds to me "none, aaabsoluutely none!". One thing I noticed is that in the examples of "any child" and "any soldiers", "any" is (to some extent) stressed when pronounced, OTOH in "any of my children/soldiers", "any" can be weak, and if stressed, its effect is to emphasize the entire sentence. (In the example of the students, "any" is usually not stressed. This might be the point.)